# What is the explanation for the Enterprise wreckage in ENT, Episode 1x16?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

At the beginning of StarTrek:Enterprise season 1 episode 16 "Shuttlepod One", the characters Malcom Reed and Trip Tucker are shown to be in a shuttlepod, navigating an asteroid field while searching for Enterprise (Enterprise is supposed to rendezvous with them at this location). However they are shocked when they discover an impact crater with the wreckage of Enterprise on a large asteroid. They assume that Enterprise has been destroyed, and the remainder of the episode largely consists of them trying to figure out a way to survive long enough to be rescued.

However it is soon revealed in another scene that enterprise is not actually destroyed, and is carrying some Aliens back to their home planet. It is revealed that Enterprise was hit by "Micro Singularities" and that the alien spacecraft crashed into the Enterprise docking bay, causing some damage. But just by watching the episode, you can see that the damage to the docking bay doesn't seem like enough to cause the massive impact crater and copious amounts of wreckage that were discovered by Malcom and Trip at the beginning of the episode.

So my question is, what in actual fact was that wreckage? Was it the Enterprise or something else? Was it just some parts from the shuttlebay doors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What they saw that let them identify it as the Enterprise was a part of its registry number, "NX-01".  However, they mentioned their sensors weren't working, so they couldn't scan the debris, and assumed the ship was destroyed.

What they actually saw though was the crashed Tesnian ship (those aliens that the Enterprise was bringing back to their home planet) with the part of the shuttlebay doors that had been knocked off.

Although the shape of the wreckage doesn't appear to match up to me, you can see how "NX" remains on the ship and "01" is in with the wreckage:

[image: Damage]
[image: Wreckage]